# Login and stay on the same page?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a sleek login function here =)

I want the "login experience" to be smooth and seamless, so I don't want the user to "feel" like he/she is being "redirected" and taken back to the same page again.

So the process goes:

1. User X visits page A
2. X is not logged in
3. X presses on Login btn (that lives in a in a div together with the form)
4. Login fields and buttons fade away
5. X is logged in and still on page A (without noticing a "redirection")

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: You will certainly want to use AJAX to do this for the partial loading of information (jQuery being my choice). Can you give us some idea of the page structure you're using (is it plain html? php? asp.net? etc..)? And please note any information that changes based on authentication (other than login buttons) so we can help with that.

Comment: It's a JAVA app running on GAE with GWT.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to re-request the same page (which should load the correct content since the session was created). It has support for loading part of the requested document.

Example:

```
function onSuccessfulLogin() {
   $("#content").load(window.location.href + " #content");
}
```

EDIT: Oops, sorry, I think I misunderstood. I thought page A had content only visible to authenticated users, and you were showing a login form and wanted the correct content to show up once they authenticated.

If you just want the async. login, you can add a submit handler to the login form that submits the form to some sort of login handler script that returns whether their login attempt was successful.

```
$("#loginform").bind("submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: "login.php",
       method: "post",
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json", // for example
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function (data) { // data is the JS object based on the JSON returned
          if (data.success) {
             $(this).fadeOut();
          } else {
             alert("bad login: "+data.error);
          }
       }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an Ajax login system that reloaded the page after a succesful login. If you don't want to reload the current page, you will need a JavaScript based system to show and hide a logged in state. (although I think that might complicate any further development)

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could accomplish this, would be to use some AJAX and a modal dialog containing the required login fields and the submit button.  You can do a slick implementation using a Dojo dialog [dijit](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog).